# How can Interface Builder interact with private IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, interface-builder, private, iboutlet

I see that IB job is to unarchive the Nib file, load the objects in the Nib and set those to IBOutlet properties. Some people even [use IB as DI framework](http://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2009/04/16/dependency-inversion-principle-and-iphone.html)

But IBOutlet can be private, I mean it can be declared in class extension or implementation section. So how can IB interact with these private IBOutlet?

```
@interface FPMovieBottomViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the **Note** here: [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

> By adding the class extension shown above, redeclaring the
> uniqueIdentifier property as a readwrite property, a
> setUniqueIdentifier: method will exist at runtime on every XYZPerson
> object, regardless of whether other source code files were aware of
> the class extension or not.
>
> The compiler will complain if code in one of those other source code files attempts to call a private method or set a readonly property, but **it’s possible to avoid compiler errors and leverage dynamic runtime features to call those methods in other ways, such as by using one of the performSelector:... methods offered by NSObject.**
> You should avoid a class hierarchy or design where this
> is necessary; instead, the primary class interface should always
> define the correct “public” interactions.
>
> **If you intend to make “private” methods or properties available to select other classes,
> such as related classes within a framework, you can declare the class
> extension in a separate header file and import it in the source files
> that need it.** It’s not uncommon to have two header files for a class,
> for example, such as XYZPerson.h and XYZPersonPrivate.h. When you
> release the framework, you only release the public XYZPerson.h header
> file.

I've highlighted the parts where we can modify existing classes with dynamic runtime. In other languages such as ruby or python this is called *monkey-patching*.

There's a good article about this: [monkeypatching-for-humans](http://blog.codinghorror.com/monkeypatching-for-humans/). But, in the example given, extension only allows one to add functionality to existing classes, not *replace*, *remove* or *override*. In objc, an accurate example of monkey patching is method-swizzling. Which is not always harmful, because developers have been taking advantage of it to build something like Xcode plugins, or [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).